# Azure Databricks - Reactivate an inactive user

Tags: azure, databricks

I'm trying to reactive a user account in Databricks. Its currently state is "inactive".

I followed this azure kb: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/users)

```bash
curl --netrc -X PATCH \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/<user-id> \
--header 'Content-type: application/scim+json' \
--data @update-user.json \
| jq .
```

I've used "true" instead of "false":

```json
{
  "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp" ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "active",
      "value": [
        {
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting this output, but the account remains inactive.

```json
{
  "emails": [
    {
      "type": "work",
      "value": "user@test.com",
      "primary": true
    }
  ],
  "displayName": "User",
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:workspace:2.0:User"
  ],
  "name": {
    "familyName": "User",
    "givenName": "User"
  },
  "externalId": "xxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxxx",
 ** "active": false,**
  "groups": [
    {
      "display": "admins",
      "type": "direct",
      "value": "99999999999",
      "$ref": "Groups/9999999999"
    }
  ],
  "id": "0000000000",
  "userName": "user@test.com"
}
```

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs seem fine, it makes me think something just maybe off with your permissions, PAT, the user id you're supplying, etc.

Here is the Python code I use almost every day here at Databricks to achieve the same effect:

```
username_to_activate = "some.user@databricks.com" 
workspace_uri = "https://<your workspace>.azuredatabricks.net" # demo
#pat = "<your pat>"
    
import requests, json 
headers = {"Authentication": f"Bearer {pat}"}
    
r = requests.get(f"{workspace_uri}/api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users?filter=userName+eq+{username_to_activate}", headers=headers)
    
user= json.loads(r.text)["Resources"][0] 
user_id = user["id"] 
is_active = user["active"] 
print(f"{username_to_activate} Active? {is_active}")
    
j = {   "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp" ],   
        "Operations": [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "active",
          "value": [
            {
              "value": "true"
            }
          ]
        }   ] }
    
r = requests.patch(f"{workspace_uri}/api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/{user_id}", headers=headers, json=j)
    
user_patch= json.loads(r.text) 
is_active = user_patch["active"] 
print(f"{username_to_activate} Active? {is_active}")
```